# PayPal Voucher activation/open issue in Safari with download pop-up

Tags: javascript, paypal, safari

If I would like to open in Safari a valid and an invalid Voucher (wrong voucher URL, on production exceeded voucher limit) in case of invalid voucher it wants to download an empty file.

[image]

In case of invalid voucher we can see a GET with 400 Status Code response that is : [image]

If I would like to open them in background in an iframe on Google Chrome, Opera, Firefox the iframe onloaded event/callback is called, but not on Safari.

I also tried in Safari to uncheck Prevent cross-site tracking.

Do you have any idea why the Safari wants to download an empty file and in iframe the onloaded event/callback is not called?

I also added a code sample
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-e9ekaa?file=index.ts